# In Highchart in R how to remove background blue?

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

This is my code:

```
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)

  hours <- c("00-02", "02-04", "04-06", "06-08", "08-10", "10-12", "12-14", "14-16", "16-18", "18-20", "20-22", "22-24")
    days <- c('Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat')
    matriz <- matrix(nrow = 12, ncol = 8)
    matriz[, 1] <- hours
    df <- data.frame(matriz)
    colnames(df) <- c("Hours", days)
    df[is.na(df)] <- sample(12:29, size = sum(is.na(df)), replace = TRUE)
    print(df)

    main_df <- df %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = Sun:Sat) %>%
      mutate(
        Hours = factor(Hours, labels = hours),
        value = round(runif(84,-1,1),2)) %>% arrange(Hours)

    hchart(main_df,"heatmap",
           hcaes(x=name,y=Hours,value= round(value,2)),
           pointWidth = 15,
           groupPadding= 10)%>%
      hc_colorAxis(minColor = '#cea3a3',
                   maxColor = '#cb4646')%>%

      hc_yAxis(
        labels = list(enabled = TRUE),
        title = list(enabled = FALSE),
        tickLength = 0,
        lineWidth = 0
      ) %>%
      hc_plotOptions(
        series = list(borderRadius = 15,
                      borderWidth = 5,
                      borderHeight = 10,
                      showInLegend= TRUE),

        heatmap = list(

          dataLabels =  list(
            enabled = TRUE,
            pointFormat = "{point.y}h",
            style =  list(
              fontWeight = 'normal',
              fontSize = '.85em')
          )
        ))
```

[image]

Why do I have this blue background color? And also the Series Legends in blue?

I believe that because of this blue background I have some "Series 1" in my chart. But I con not find out.

Any help?

Comment: If you want to change the background color, add color to the `series` list, if you want to get ride of the `● Series`, change `showInLegend` to `FALSE`. For example: `series = list(borderRadius = 15, borderWidth = 5, borderHeight = 10, color = "white", showInLegend= F),`...